# DataContractSerializer Deserialize list not working

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I have to deserialize the following XML received from a provider

```
<desc>
    <l_error>
         <error>Error 1</error>
         <error>Error 2</error>
    </l_error>
</desc>
```

To do I I'm using DataContractSerializer, I have defined the following classes to deserialize it

```
[CollectionDataContract(Name = "desc", Namespace = "")]
public class DescriptionError : List<Error>
{
}

[DataContract(Name = "l_error", Namespace = "")]
public class Error
{
    [DataMember(Name = "error")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And a generic method do deserialize

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(string text)
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = text.ToStream())
    {
         var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
         return (T)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
    }
}
```

The problem is when I Deserialize the above XML the DescriptionError object returned only contains one element, the first "error 1" ,the second error item in the XML is not in DescriptionError. I'm not able to figure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the best way to solve this is to work the other way round - create your objects and serialize them to see what XML you'll get.

If you look at what you have, you have something that seems to imply a single `desc` element with multiple `l_error` children which contain a single `error`.  Obviously this doesn't match what your XML is.

This is more what you want - a single `desc` element that contains an `l_error` element containing multiple `error` string elements.

```
[DataContract(Name = "desc", Namespace = "")]
public class Desc
{
    [DataMember(Name = "l_error")]
    public LError LError { get; set; }
}

[CollectionDataContract(ItemName = "error", Namespace = "")]
public class LError : List<string>
{    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your object class should look like You can use http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/ to get c# class from XML

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace MyNamespace
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName="l_error")]
    public class L_error {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="error")]
        public List<string> Error { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="desc")]
    public class Desc {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="l_error")]
        public L_error L_error { get; set; }
    }

}
```

You have wrong `public string Description { get; set; }` which should look like `public List<string> Description { get; set; }`

Comment: These attributes are for XmlSerializer, I'm using DataContractSerializer to deserialize.

Comment: Because you are giving me a solution of XmlSerializer and I'm asking for a problem related to DataContractSerializer

Comment: yea but under the XmlSerializer is the real problem :) I posted XmlSerializer just for comparison of your code and you can clearly see that you re missing a `public List<string> Error` which is in your case `public List<string> Description`

Comment: XmlSerializer and DataContractSerializer are unrelated classes and treats Collections in a different way each one. Take a look at http://www.kongsli.net/2010/02/01/parsing-xml-using-xmlserializer-or-datacontractserializer/

Comment: Iam talking about structure, can you say if your case is solved or you have more problems ?

Comment: It's no solved with your example, this structure it's not right for DataContractSerializer.